# Is this a Safari bug? Using flexbox and resizing past a certain size shows empty white space

Tags: css, safari

I'm only seeing this on Safari 13

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="headerContent">
        Desktop
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page">
    <div id="sideBar">
        <div>
            box 1
        </div>
        <div>
            box 2
        </div>
        <div id="toggle">toggle me</div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#header {
    height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(#444444, #333333);
    color: #bbbbbb;
}

#headerContent {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#toggle {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3000;
    padding: .5rem;
}

#page {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
}

#sideBar {
    width: 100px;
    background: darkblue;
}

#content {
    background: lightgrey;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

When I refresh the page if its a small window and start expanding the safari browser, it stops at a certain point (I have no hard heights defined) doesn't fill the rest of the page (see picture). However, when I refresh the page with it stretching fully vertically, its fine. Is this a safari bug or am I missing something else?

[image]

Comment: You reference `it` a few times in your question but you don't give a clear indication of what `it` represents. Please provide context for `it`

Comment: Done, thanks @justinw